# Creating firebase functions, google sample not working

Tags: javascript, android, function, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a cloud function that sends a notification when i write to my database, I'm almost clueless at javascript so I'm trying to use one of google samples [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/Node-8/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js) but theyre using syntax that my node.js didnt like so I've updated tools and added the node 8 engine according to [this](https://howtofirebase.com/cloud-functions-migrating-to-node-8-9640731a8acc) to my package.json but i still get an error when trying to deploy this functions the error is

```
Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Is there a syntax error in your code?
Detailed stack trace: /user_code/index.js:9
    .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
                   ^
```

can anyone help me to fix this please here is my entire index.js script

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup 
triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = 
functions.database
.ref('/user/{userId}/contacts/{contactId}/messages/{messageId}')
.onWrite(async (change, context) => {
  const senderId = context.params.userId;
  const recipientId = context.params.contactId;
  // If update or delete we exit the function
  if (!change.after.val()) {
    return console.log('User updated or deleted');
  }
  //get the message
  const message = change.data.current.val();

  console.log('We have a new message for ', recipientId, ' from user: ', senderId);

  // Get the recipient profile.
  const getRecipientProfile = await admin.auth().getUser(recipientId);
  //get token
  const token = getRecipientProfile.registeredToken;

  // Notification details.
  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: 'New message',
      body: message.message,
      icon: getRecipientProfile.user_small_image
    }
  };

  // Send notification

  admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        });

});
```

and my package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
  "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
  "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
  "start": "npm run shell",
  "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
  "logs": "firebase functions:log"
},
"engines": {
  "node": "8"
},
"dependencies": {
  "firebase-admin": "~5.12.1",
  "firebase-functions": "^1.0.3"
},
"private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try changing

```
.onWrite(async (change, context) =>
```

for

```
.onWrite((change, context) =>
```

Basically delete `async`.

Comment: this and removing await allowed me to deploy the functions many thanks

Comment: The problem is that in some cases, you absolutely need the async/await ... and removing it from your code causes your function will not work anymore. I have the same problem with the Google Cloud Function example : https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/generate-thumbnail. Removing async/await doesn't solve the problem. The deploy succeeds but the function doesn't work.

Comment: I've got the same issue as well. However removing the async and await breaks the function.